# EF re-adding FK columns after adding ICollection navigation property

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following classes, that already have their tables created and defined using EF migrations:

```
[Table("Account")]
public class AccountEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
}

[Table("Request")]
public class RequestEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public int? AccountID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AccountID")]
    public virtual AccountEntity Account { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Request` table, this properly created the FK `FK_dbo.Request_dbo.Account_AccountID`

Using SSMS, I can confirm the FK is setup properly.

In order to be able to access the `Request's` one-to-many property from the `Account` entity, I added the following property to the `AccountEntity` class:

```
public virtual ICollection<RequestEntity> Requests { get; set; }
```

However, now EF suspects that I need to run migrations due to domain changes.

Here's the migration class that it creates, and wants to run:

```
public partial class RequestUpdate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Request", "AccountEntity_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Request", "AccountEntity_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Request", "AccountEntity_Id", "dbo.Account", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Request", "AccountEntity_Id", "dbo.RealtorAccount");
        DropIndex("dbo.Request", new[] { "AccountEntity_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Request", "AccountEntity_Id");
    }
}
```

As you can see, EF seems to not recongize/respect that the FK relationshp has already been setup.

I don't suspect that any migrations need to be setup. The FK is already established, and I'm simply adding the collection "navigation" property.

Migrations need to be enabled for this project. EF version is 6, .NET 4.5.

Comment: Is there a relevant fluent API configuration not shown in the post?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way this can happen is if you have used fluent configuration like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RequestEntity>()
    .HasOptional(e => e.Account)
    .WithMany();
```

and forgot to update the `.WithMany()` to `.WithMany(e => e.Requests)` after introducing the collection navigation property, in which case EF considers **two** one-to-many relationships, hence adds a second FK column with default name.